# iPhone: how to stop Record Automated tests in Instruments

Tags: iphone, testing, automated-tests

I wrote some scripts for automation testing, then I put them in .js file. And using Instruments, I start them by taping on Record button. What I want to know, is there any way to stop recording in script ? Because, if my Test1 fail, I don't want Test2 to be run. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If you record with xctrace you can capture the pid of the xctrace process and terminate it later:

```bash
# Start recording
xcrun xctrace record \
    --device <device> \
    --attach <pid|name> \
    --template <path|name> \
    --time-limit 5m \
    --no-prompt \
    --output recording.trace \
    >> trace.log \
    &
    2>&1 \

xctracePID=$!
```

Stop recording:

```
# Send Interupt signal (Ctrl-C)
kill -INT $xctracePID 2>/dev/null

# Wait for recording to be saved to disk
wait $xctracePID 2>/dev/null
```